# How to make my php add text on another line

Tags: php, list, line, addition

In my PHP script which make a new file and adds text to it.
http://localhost/chatpro/chat.php?w=1text

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['w'];
$logfile= 'chatroom.chat';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "a");
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This makes a new file called chatroom.chat
In this file I have got the text

```
1
```

But when adding new text http://localhost/chatpro/chat.php?w=2text
I get

```
1text2text
```

I would like it so it does not add the 2 right next to the one but puts in underneath like a list
For example

```
1text
2text
```

Answer (score 1):

**PHP_EOL** is a predefined constant in PHP since PHP 4.3.10 and PHP 5.0.2. See the manual posting:

Using this will save you extra coding on cross platform developments.

Just change your code to the following.

```
<?php
$msg = $_GET['w'].PHP_EOL;
$logfile= 'chatroom.chat';
$fp = fopen($logfile, "a");
fwrite($fp, $msg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: great solution!! Worked excellent for me

Answer (score 0):

You need to append an enter char ("\n") on each line. Some like:

```
$msg = $_GET['w']."\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that adding the string "\r\n" to the end of the line. Use double quotes or it won't work.